# Making AngularJS view rendering less lenient during development

Tags: angularjs

From what I've read, Angular is quite lenient when rendering views.  If an expression is undefined, Angular doesn't log an error for example.  Is there a way to turn this off during development so that I can see that something is wrong in the view?

Thanks.

**Update:** Rendering of strings via `{{ }}` is what comes to mind.

Comment: This strongly depends; if you're referring to the rendering of strings via `{{ }}`, then that's a point to be made; if you're referring to an entire view component not working, I'd be surprised to *not* see some  kind of console error.

Comment: Taking the problem by the back, maybe you could TDD with e2e testing, preventing from none displayed items